# htaccess changes doesnt respnd the way as it should to clean URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

I have bunch of URLs

```
http://www.mydomain.com/aboutUs.php
http://www.mydomain.com/contactUs.php
```

and so on....

The Rewrite Rule I wrote in my .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ contactUs.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ aboutUs.php
```

and so on...

Now when I use the clean URL, let say for example,

```
http://www.mydomain.com/aboutUs
```

It points to homepage always...i.e. `http://www.mydomain.com/`, BUT the URL remains `http://www.mydomain.com/aboutUs`

And similar behaviour for other URLs as well.

Also the images in the banner doesnt appear while using clean URL... As I have used a `src` attribute for images as `<?php echo HTTP_PATH;?>images/header-logo.png`

Where, `HTTP_PATH = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])`

Could someone guide me whats wrong with the .htaccess or is it anything else?

> **UPDATE as per @HAKRE Comment**

I need the URL to look like  `http://www.mydomain.com/aboutUs` and it should point to  `http://www.mydomain.com/aboutUs.php`

Comment: Your `htaccess` is kinda weird: you have 2 rules that trigger on exact the same regex? How do you suppose that would work?

Comment: Agreed +1 to you, Then How I am supposed to direct a specific file to specific name?

Comment: Usign global with `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ 1$.php` ?

Comment: @Bora When I did so, I recieved an error `Not Found The requested URL /1$.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: It looks like before all the technical details how to do something, you miss to explain what you actually want to do (apart from any specific webserver or programming language you're using). I bet there is a problem with formulating that, not how to press it in code. Just fix the problem at the right place.

Comment: Look For Update as per comment of @hakre

Comment: `RewriteRule ^\QaboutUs\E$ aboutUs.php` - you find that in the mod-rewrite manual. Just remove any other `RewriteRule` you have there so they can not bite each other.

Comment: What does this ^\Q......\E$ stands for?

Comment: You really need to spend 5 minutes reading a tutorial before firing off questions like this.

Comment: That whole thing is a so called regular expression. Those can have different dialects, the mod rewrite documentation tells you it uses the PCRE dialect which is also the same dialect as PHP does. You find it explained all here: http://pcre.org/.

Comment: And better than a tutorial, first read the manual. That normally requires more understanding but helps you much better for the rest of your live. So worth the time to invest. Life's Too Short.

Comment: btw. the manual is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/ - and the directives reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Many Many Thanks to all who guided me.. especially to @hakre ...

Answer (score 0):

Try and use a redirect; put a [R] after the rewrite statement, or [R,L] if you want apache to stop there.  Or you can use [R=301] format eg to send a 301 permanent redirect code as well.

So a row looks like this:
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ contactUs.php  [R]

hope this helps.